# PHP - Relative path to folder?

Tags: php, codeigniter, relative-path

I am using an MVC `codeigniter` for a project I am working on. It is running on `localhost` just find and has a defined `base_url='http://localhost/app/`.

When running on the local machine, everything is working fine as expected and the images etc have a path that looks like: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/app/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

The issue I am facing is when I use a VPN on my phone to look at the site. When on my local network, I type in the IP address of the server to load the website. This then causes images / css etc to still try and load from `http://localhost` and thus does not load them.

Is there a PHP variable that I can use that will get me the path to the folder the files are in? ie. `../../assets/bootstrap.min.css`?

I tried using things like `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` but this gives me the full path `/var/www/html/app/assets/css/` which again, isn't valid when I try to load this from another source such as my VPN.

How could I go about solving for this? Is this a path issue or something with the server I need to look into?

Comment: Set up a local domain on the development server. Then set up hosts-files on both server, and the machine accessing the server, and so on. Besides, there is no reason using full urls. Just use /app/assets... And so on. Basically / means root of the web server, and everything is based on that. This is basically development server 101

Answer (score 1):

When you are wanting to collect files within the website you do not need to specify the url.

So if you have a domain whether it be localhost or a fqdn it doesnt matter and makes websites "portable"

Your links/images/script uri's can all be called relatively.

```
<a href="relative/path/to/file.html">
<img src="path/to/image.jpg">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/file.css">
<script src="path/to/file.css">
```

Doing this will overcome the portability issue, you will do the same in php some of the functions require the absolute path and those are documented but many allow you to use relative paths if you need a file from an adjacent directory you would use ../path/to/file etc.

Defining the path constant.

```
define('ROOTPATH', '/path/to/webroot');
```

From here I can combine my constant with the relative path wherever needed:

```
ROOTPATH . '/path/to/file'
```

Comment: Only caveat to this I would say is to use root-relative urls; just change `relative/path/to/file.jpg` to `/relative/path/to/file.jpg` (with a `/` at the front).

Comment: The issue I had with this though is due to the controller URL's and what not, its accounting for those. For example, if my index page was loading `../assets/file.css` but then i access a controller `/admin/user/123` now the `../` put the path to the user directory.

Comment: Yes root relative (absolute paths) would be better within the program I find defining the path constant in a config file useful for portability, you just use the contant across the application so that if you really cannot avoid a change of path then you at least only have to change one line of code.

Comment: @willoller And what happens when you change hosts and the full path changes?!?!?!? Recode ?!?!??!

Comment: Wait @RiggsFolly I think you missed what I meant there; relative urls are relative to the current full url, while root-relative urls are relative to the domain. Using root-relative urls makes the paths the same for all urls in the domain, regardless of the domain or (usually) hosting configuration. (Unless the hosting also changes your root or _base_ url, i.e. `domain.com/app/...` becomes `newhosting.com/hosting/app/...`)

Comment: / paths within a php application are not relative to the webroot as you might expect but to the file system. For example: /path/to/file would most likely be /var/www/file /var/www/html/file or /home/<user>/public_html/file depending on the distribution. path/to/file would be from the directory holding the php file calling it.

Comment: @Chris Yep; I'm taking about root-relative HTML paths, not PHP paths. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: I learned something new, i will have to check into that, ive always used the parent directory short cut when needed. Granted if the code im working on is several directories deep that actually becomes a pain to remember how deep you are at all times.. ../../../../ especially when most of the time you are linking into a first subdirectory level anyway. /path/file would certainly improve readability.

Answer (score -2):

I too faced the same issue. There seems to be a problem in the slash between views and html. Instead of back slash it contains forward slash. Work around: go to index.php and stop error logging by defining -1 to 0 as given below according to the environment.

Time being solution/work around:
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(0);

Error message:
Warning: include(D:\xampp\htdocs\IPT\application\views/errors\html\error_php.php)